# Config on Clustering Couchdb 2.0

Tags: database, configuration, couchdb, cluster-computing, nodes

Setting up a 2 node cluster. One node (database) runs on our main production server and the other node runs at our warehouse. The connection to the warehouse is very bad.

What configuration would you suggest to make sure that documents are always are available to the local server?

I find the documentation confusing.

http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/cluster/theory.html

```
[cluster]
q=8
r=2
w=2
n=3
q - The number of shards.
r - The number of copies of a document with the same revision that 
have to be read before CouchDB returns with a 200 and the document. If 
there is only one copy of the document accessible, then that is 
returned with 200.
w - The number of nodes that need to save a document before a write is 
returned with 201. If the nodes saving the document is <w but >0, 202 
is returned.
n - The number of copies there is of every document. Replicas.
```

From this I think my configuration should be

```
q=8 - To allow up to 8 nodes, not that we plan to but no harm?
r=1 - Only need to read the local copy?
w=1 - Only need to write to the local copy?
n=2 - Should this just be the number of nodes so you can always go 
down to one node? So if I had 4 nodes n=4?
```

Also I believe these configs need to be setup before your create the database as that is when the sharding happens. Are there any other issues I should be aware of? Such as the config on joining databases to the cluster

I have attempted to setup this config locally and I get failed to read database issues when a server goes down.

All help appreciated, many thanks.

Ryan

Comment: Since your databases aren't co-located, you may be better off setting up 2 single-node instances with replication between them instead of as a cluster.

Comment: The nice thing about clustering is any table/database that is created is automatically replicated rather than having to be setup. You are right it may be the better approach. Experience is what I will get after I need it :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm not nearly as familiar with the new clustering feature as I am old-school replication, so definitely what I'll reach for first :P

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have 3 nodes minimum due to quorom, otherwise you risk getting a split brain situation.  That is much more likely over bad connections.